# Binding richtext field with two controls in xpages

Tags: xpages

I have a richtext field in the form to enter text and store attachments. In xpages, i have used multiline edit box control to enter text and file upload control to attach files in richtext field. Both the controls are binded to same richtext field.

> If I attach file using file upload control and enter text in multiline edit box, i see the text being stored in the document and attachment being omitted. How to achieve in storing both attachment and text in the richtext field ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't bind 2 controls to one backend field. They will overwrite each other. Keep them separate. For your specific problem the [RichText Editor Evolution](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uyae_Pu28zI) might be the solution. It uses a bean to put things together.

You will need to change your RichText to "store MIME"